# Creating a Visual Studio solution from an existing solution in git (VS 2017)

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, visual-studio-2017

I am new to git. I have installed the VS git extension and I'm trying to create a local solution on my computer, from an existing solution on git. As far as I understand, the clone command creates a local copy of the git folder in my personal computer (in /Source/Repos). I cloned the git solution and can see the files of the solution under the git sidebar in VS, but I don't understand how can I actually create a local VS solution (under the VS projects folder) from this git folder. Thanks!

Comment: If this is not originally a visual studio project (C++, C#, etc.), you may have many difficulties with getting this to work. In that case, you would need to look at the makefile or other non-vs configuration and build a solution and projects from that.

Comment: Thanks, but it is originally a VS project (specifically C#).

Comment: I would expect then that there would be a `.sln` file under source control that should be somewhere in your working copy. If not, you would need to create an empty solution and add the C# projects to it.

Comment: And this file should enable me create a VS solution from the git folder?

Comment: A solution (`.sln`) is typically a collection of projects (`.csproj`, `.cxproj`, etc.). While VS2017 can open a folder, you generally want to work with a solution. If those files don't exist, you have to make them yourself (and know what the project created intended!), which is why these files would normally be included in a repository. In other words: if this is a Visual Studio project, it should have the Visual Studio project files for you to open.

Comment: I got it, thank you!